# How to create a TCP listener?

Tags: shell, networking, tcp

**Introduction:** I have created a bash function that is able to check whether a port is available and increments it by 1 if false until a certain maximum port number. E.g., if port 500 is unavailable then the availability of 501 will be checked until 550.

**Aim:** In order to test this bash function I need to create a range of ports that are in LISTEN state.

**Attempts:** On Windows it is possible to create a LISTEN port using [these PowerShell commands](http://opensysblog.directorioc.net/2014/01/powershell-listen-on-tcp-port.html):

```
PS C:\Users\u> netstat -nat | grep 1234
PS C:\Users\u> $listener = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener]1234
PS C:\Users\u> $listener.Start();
PS C:\Users\u> netstat -nat | grep 1234
TCP    0.0.0.0:1234           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
PS C:\Users\u> $listener.Stop();
PS C:\Users\u> netstat -nat | grep 1234
PS C:\Users\u>
```

Based on this I was trying to think about a command that could do the same on CentOS, but I do not know why and I started to Google without finding a solution that solves this issue.

**Expected answer**: I will accept and upvote the answer that contains a command that is able to create a LISTEN port and once the command has been run the port should stay in LISTEN state, i.e.:

```
[user@host ~]$ ss -nat | grep 500
LISTEN     0      128                       *:500                       *:*
```

Comment: On a side note: it's possible to find the listening ports without going through all this dance.  On Linux: `netstat -an --tcp | awk '/LISTEN/ {sub(".*:", "", $4); print $4}' | sort -nu`.  On *BSD: `netstat -an -f inet -p tcp  | awk '/LISTEN/ {sub(".*\\.", "", $4); print $4}' | sort -nu`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You could use `nc -l` as a method to do what you are looking for. Some implementations of `nc` have a `-L` option which allows the connections to persist.

If you only need them for a little while you could open this command in a `for` loop and have a bunch of ports opened that way.

If you need these opened longer you can use one of the super servers to create a daemon.

Comment: Instead of `-L` I would suggest: 
`-k`, `--keep-open` accept multiple connections in listen mode

Answer (score 86):

you can create a port listener using Netcat .

```
root@ubuntu:~# nc -l 5000
```

you can also check if port is open or not using netstat command .

```
root@vm-ubuntu:~# netstat -tulpen | grep nc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          710327      17533/nc
```

you can also check with nc :

Netcat Server listener  :

```
nc -l localhost 5000
```

Netcat Client :

```
root@vm-ubuntu:~# nc -v localhost 5000
Connection to localhost 5000 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

if port is not open

```
root@vm-ubuntu:~# nc -v localhost 5000
nc: connect to localhost port 5000 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

Comment: I had to specify the port with `-p` or it didn't work: `nc -l -p 1234`

Comment: nc -l 12345 
worked in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: For those with `/bin/nc --> nc.traditional` (e.g. debian), use the `-p` option, as @Leahkim advised, above.

Answer (score 10):

Listen using netcat.

```
# nc -l 5555
```

Check using ss

```
# ss -nat|grep 5555
LISTEN     0      1                         *:5555                     *:*
#
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that Debian's `netcat` package has a different implementation where (at least) you need to provide the port via the `-p` option and the `-k` option doesn't work. You might run into this issue using Docker.

`sudo apt install -y netcat`

`nc -l -p 1337`

You may consider using `openbsd-netcat` instead where the `-k` option works.

Answer (score 6):

Below python code is helpful to open a dummy port

```
'''    Simple socket server using threads
'''
import socket
import sys
HOST = ''   # Symbolic name, meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 5500 # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'
#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()
print 'Socket bind complete'
#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'
#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
s.close()
```

Save the file and run it with python command as shown below

```
~]# python portlistener.py
Socket created
Socket bind complete
Socket now listening
```

Then you can verify from required machine.

Answer (score 1):

Below command was immediately exiting without listening on port on RHEL 6
nc -l localhost 5000

For me below command worked where netcat started listening on port.
nc -lk localhost 5000